# Allow page authors to view their page regardless of paid membership status (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Woo Commerce membership plugin on a Wordpress site, which restricts content based on membership tier. I have authors who have not paid for memberships, and would like them to always be able to view the pages which they authored.

I'm thinking the code prior to page load would say something to the effect of: If current user is the author, ignore woo commerce plugin.

Any suggestions on where/how I can add the proper code to make this change? Or perhaps a better approach than the one I suggested?

Thank you.

Comment: Anything like an access management plugin any use? https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/custom-woocommerce-roles-admin-capabilities/  or https://www.sellwithwp.com/building-a-membership-site-with-woocommerce-memberships/

Comment: Something similar - where you have is_user_logged_in()  or is author - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-only-my-posts-in-the-loop-if-im-a-logged-in-user  combined with this approach https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/